# Simple ways to generate container cmd with repeated parameters from inputs.parameters in Argo Workflows

Tags: argo-workflows

In, Argo Workflows, I'd like to create a container template that runs a cmd that can specify a parameter multiple times. Like the following:

```
container:
  args: [
      'cmd',
      '--param={{inputs.parameters.paramArray[0]}}',
      '--param={{inputs.parameters.paramArray[1]}}',
      '--param={{inputs.paramters.paramArray[2]}}']
```

To accomplish this, I could always just generate a string via a script template step to create this.

However, I was wondering if there is a simple way to:

1.) Supply an array of strings for `inputs.parameters.paramArray`.

2.) Repeat/iterate through this array as I create the container cmd.